# Nginx redirect wildcard subdomain with www prefix to non-www wildcard subdomain

Tags: nginx

If you're serving an application at `*.example.tld`, how would you set it up so that http and https traffic for `www.*.example.tld` gets redirected correctly to `*.example.tld`?

Current nginx config looks like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name *.example.tld;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name *.example.tld;

    #ssl stuff ...
    #location stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use a regular expression `server_name` to capture the part of the domain name following the `www.` prefix. From [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) you will notice that wildcard `server_name` statements are higher precedence, which means that they do not mix well with regular expressions.

The order of `server` blocks with regular expression `server_name` statements is significant, as they are evaluated in order until a match is found.

There are a number of ways to organise this, depending on how strict you need it to be and whether this IP address only needs to handle `*.example.com`.

The following example does not include any SSL configuration statements.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name  ~^www\.(?<domain>.+)$;
    return 301 https://$domain$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name  ~(^|\.)example\.com$;

    #ssl stuff ...
    #location stuff...
}
```

The first block matches any domain beginning with `www.` and redirects to the same domain without the `www.` prefix.

The second block is a generic `http` to `https` redirection.

The third block is probably unnecessary as it only matches domains that are not `*.example.com`.

The final block matches `example.com` and anything that ends with `.example.com` which has not already matched the first block.